# “He told me that Trump will/would win the re-election.” Will or Would?

Tags: indirect-speech, will-would

> He told that Trump {will/would} win the re-election.

I know "will" should be used in the present tense. What is confusing me is that: his words were said in the past, but his statement is actually a prediction about an event that is in the future.

Comment: I would use *will* if talking about an event in the future, and *would* if talking about an election that Trump won in the past or about a hypothetical future situation (e.g., "Trump would win a third term if the law allowed him to run.").

Comment: You can use "will" instead of "would" for future conditional clauses: "It will be a sad day for all of us if the theatre is forced to close." - Oxford Learner's Dictionary - https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sad_1

Comment: Either one is syntactically and semantically valid.  Which is best depends on the larger context.

Answer (score -1):

- He told me that Trump will win re-election.

The sentence structure is (subject + verb + indirect object + direct object)
The direct object is the noun phrase "Trump will win re-election". This is an independent clause. "*Trump will win re-election." is a valid, standalone, sentence. And therefore, a valid independent clause.

- He told me that Trump would win re-election.

"*Trump would win re-election*" should also be an independent clause to be valid grammar. However, that clause starts out in the subjunctive mood, and then stops.... So, that is not a valid clause. You have the subjunctive mood, and the way to finish a sentence in the subjunctive mood might be:

**Trump would win re-election**
"... were Hillary to run again."
"... were Biden selected as the nominee."
"... if Trump were to get impeached for financial crimes."

Comment: Sometimes the info completing the clause is dropped if supplied by context. [Q] What if Hillary ran again? [A] Trump would win reelection. This can be converted to reported speech, although I don't think it works as smoothly.

Comment: A month ago he told me that Trump would win re-election.  Now he's not so sure.